# expo start on CLI fails

Tags: react-native, expo

`expo start` worked well, but after trying to build ios standalone app with `expo build:ios`, `expo start` fails with error message:

```
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
error Unrecognized command "start".

info Run "react-native --help" to see a list of all available commands.
Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
Error: Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/@expo/xdl@57.9.9/src/Project.ts:1838:16)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:428:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
```

I tried reinstalling expo-cli with yarn globally, but it does not fix the problem.

`expo diagnotics` outputs as:

```
  Expo CLI 3.20.9 environment info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.15.2
      Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 13.6.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.21.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.13.4 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    IDEs:
      Xcode: 11.4.1/11E503a - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      expo: ^36.0.2 => 36.0.2
      react: ~16.9.0 => 16.9.0
      react-dom: ~16.9.0 => 16.9.0
      react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz => 0.61.4
      react-native-web: ^0.12.1 => 0.12.2
```

Comment: Could you copy paste the output from `expo diagnostics` here? It includes information that would make it easier to help with this issue.

Comment: @fson I've edited my question to include the output of `expo diagnostics`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error after trying to use React native for windows (and then removing it from the project), because of some wrong path references messing in files: react-native.config.js and metro.config.js. I've just deleted them and it works now.